# Where can I find this Ramban on Chanuka?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chanuka, ramban

From the [Chabad website](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2047693/jewish/Seven-Times-Straight.htm):

> There is a segula1 from the Ramban for after lighting the Chanukah lights to say the verse from Psalms: "May the graciousness of the L·rd our G·d be upon us," (Psalms 90:17) repeating each word seven times. This is very good to do.

Does anyone know where I can read the original Ramban?

Comment: Source is apparently in The Siddur of R. Shabsai, anyone have that?

Comment: @RabbiKaii there are two famous siddurim by Rabbis Shabsai. One by R Shabsai of Permeisla and one by R Shabsai of Roshokov

Comment: The one mentioned  in Sefer Baal Shem Tov; translation and commentary by Rabbi Dr. Eliezer Shore, which I also don't have

Comment: @RabbiKaii In that case, it would be [R' Shabsai of Rashkov](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/shabbetai-ben-zevi-hirsch-raszkow), not [R' Shabsai Sofer of Premyshl](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8).